# complex numbers around infinity

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I have to deal with the following task:

We expand the Complex plane around the point of infinity and set $\mathbb{\overline{C}}:=\mathbb{C} \cup{\infty}$.

$\sigma:\mathbb{\overline{C}}\rightarrow \mathbb{\overline{C}}, \begin{equation}
   z \rightarrow
   \begin{cases}
     z^{-1} & \text{if } z\in \mathbb{C}^{\times} \\
     \infty & \text{if } z=0 \\
     0 & \text{if } z = \infty 
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}$

a) explain $\sigma$ geometrical

b) Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $G_{x_0}:=({z\in\mathbb{C} | Re(z)=x_0})\cup(\infty)\subset\mathbb{\overline{C}}$

Determine the image of $\sigma$.

I know this is not a platform to solve homeworks but I'm utterly lost with this task, there for I don't really have an own approach. First of all, what does the cross in  "$z\in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$" mean?
I know complex numbers are in the form of a+bi where. where a is my real part and b my imaginary part. And a + bi can be viewed as a vector. Still I have no approach how to solve this task. Not even an idea for task b). I need some patient guidance.

Thank you in advance

Comment: a) What i would do here is make a geometrical explanation using a metter 3d graf. What u have is a kind of hyperbolic function with $z \rightarrow 0$ when $z=0$ ,$z \rightarrow \infty$ when $z=0$. U can see that by using $z^{-1} = \frac{a}{a^2 + b^2} - \frac{b}{a^2 + b^2}i$ do the geometry alone using the fact that the real part is the real part of $z$ divided by its meter and the imaginary part is the imaginary part of z divided by its meter 
PS the cross means all complex numbers besides 0

Comment: The cross means multiplicative group of the complex numbers. i.e. without $0$, as the action on $0$ is seperately defined. And for a), hint: $z^{-1}=\bar z/|z|^2$

Comment: For b), why don't you try to plot a graph, choosing a suitable $x_0$, and calculate some inverses of $z$ s.t. $Re(z)=x_0$? Anyway it is a semicircle without endpoints plus a point $0$.

Comment: @Pookaros
Why is it a semicircle? if I put b=1 and a=1,2,......17 I get something like a hyperbole?

Comment: @the_asdf_word https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2Fz this may help u. I think i said nothing about a semicircle. What u have to be careful about is that there is a pole on $0$ but the values around it might not be homonymous.

Comment: @Pookaros thanks for your reply. I'm still working on it